# visual format language and vary for traits

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint, image-resizing

Hello everybody: I did layout all my subviews properly into a scroll view, using visual format language. I need to keep the square aspect ratio of my images for different size classes, so according to according to the literature here found, I add an anchor constraint to keep the aspect ratio like this one:

```
montanaView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: montanaView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
```

When I use vary for traits the square ratio is broken. It does no follow.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

EUREKA. I tried something have not thought before. I did decrease the with priorities of the with dimensions (This is a horizontal scroll view and the with must follow the height when you change this size in vary for traits). So this was the solution.